# PHP: Passing URL Parameter in IF and ELSE statement

Tags: php, if-statement, parameters, url-parameters

I'm trying to pass an URL parameter in an IF and ELSE statement. This is how the initial code looks like with just the link and without the parameter:

```
 <?php 

    if ($row_checklist_finding_final['item_class'] == "Major")   
    {
        echo '<a href="UserNCR.php">Go to NCR</a>';
    }

    else
    {
        echo '<a href="UserOFI.php">Go to OFI</a>';
    }
?>
```

Usually when I'm trying to pass an URL parameter I use this code (this is without if and else statement:

```
<a href="UserNCR.php?item_id=<?php echo $row_checklist_finding_final['item_id']; ?>">
    Go to NCR
</a>
```

So what I did is, I use my usual way of putting the parameter in the link like this.
The parameter name is `item_id` which is equal to value `$row_checklist_finding_final['item_id']`

```
<?php 
    if ($row_checklist_finding_final['item_class'] == "Major")   
    {
        <a href="UserNCR.php?item_id=<?php echo $row_checklist_finding_final['item_id']; ?>">Go to NCR</a>
    }

    else
    {
        '<a href="UserOFI.php">Go to OFI</a>';
    }
?>
```

I also tried removing the redundant `<?php ?>` like this:

```
  <?php 
    if ($row_checklist_finding_final['item_class'] == "Major")   
    {
        <a href="UserNCR.php?item_id= echo $row_checklist_finding_final['item_id'];">Go to NCR</a>
    }

    else
    {
        '<a href="UserOFI.php">Go to OFI</a>';
    }
?>
```

But there are still error.
Did I use the wrong syntax?
What should I do to pass the URL parameter in an IF and ELSE statement?

Comment: The sample is likely vulnerable to HTML injection/[cross-site scripting](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) and possibly produces invalid HTML in some cases. See "[How to prevent XSS with HTML/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1996122/90527)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this below

```
<?php 
  if ($row_checklist_finding_final['item_class'] == "Major")   
  {
    echo ' <a href="UserNCR.php?item_id='.$row_checklist_finding_final["item_id"].'">Go to NCR</a>';
  }
  else
  {
    echo '<a href="UserOFI.php">Go to OFI</a>';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the . concatenation operator to join variables together, e.g. as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45666738/5233704

Another way is to use double quotes for your string as these allow inclusion of variables. Arrays need to be surrounded by curly brackets when doing this:

```
 <?php 
    if ($row_checklist_finding_final['item_class'] == "Major")   
    {
        echo "<a href=\"UserNCR.php?item_id={$row_checklist_finding_final['item_id']\">Go to NCR</a>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="UserOFI.php">Go to OFI</a>';
    }
?>
```

Note that any double quotes inside your string need to be escaped with a backslash.